# Mongoose query.remove() callback not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been banging my head against the desk for about 2 hours on this issue, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Here's the problem code:

```
/* Users */

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    a: String,
    d: String
});

var removeByDeviceToken = function(device_token, callback) {

    this.findOne({ d: device_token }, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else if (user) {
            user.remove(function(error) {
                callback(error);
            });
        } else {
            callback(new Error("No users with that device token were found."));
        }
    });
};

User["static"]("removeByDeviceToken", removeByDeviceToken);
mongoose.model("User", User);
```

The problem is quite simply that the callback for user.remove() is not being called. (The user itself isn't being removed either.)

Thanks!

**EDIT**: After some more testing, it appears that the middleware I have defined for removals is being called.  It also might be relevant that I'm hosting the DB on MongoHQ.

**EDIT #2**: After days of testing, it turns out the issue was because in the middleware I had defined for removals, I forgot to call the next() function. *facepalm*

Comment: Just a quick notice, shouldn't you be doing `User.static.removeByDeviceToken = removeByDeviceToken` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  To be honest, I'm not quite sure.  I've seen it used this way and it seems to work xD . The method is being called alright in this case.

Comment: Please post your own answer then accept it. Watch out for forgetting to call next() or forgetting to pass null for the error to a success callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days of testing, it turns out the issue was because in the middleware I had defined for removals, I forgot to call the next() function. facepalm

Comment: i am facing same issue with remove method, my document is removing from db but callback was not firing.